# Feature Engineering: What we call the process that generate values of features from dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction

I know that the feature generation means generating new features from the original features and feature extraction means selecting features from the a set of features. So what we call the process that we get the value of each featrue from dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems too broad. Still, I'll try to help you. It seems you are talking about [Missing value imputation](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-handle-missing-data-8646b18db0d4). It is process under the exploratory data analysis step, in which we place some dummy values based on logic on the place of missing values instead of deleting them, so that we don't lack data. Hope it helps.
Happy Learning!

Comment: I think I havent described my question clearly. I want to know the process that I already know the features and have the dataset, then through the PROCESS to get the each features value.

Comment: You'll have to find the correlation between the features and outcome i.e. dependent and independent variables. More is the correlation, more is value of that feature i.e. it defines the dependent variable better.

Answer (score 0):

There is a gap in your understanding of :

*I know that the feature generation means generating new features from the original features and feature extraction means selecting features from the a set of features.*

**Feature selection** means selecting a sub-set of features from a available set of features. You need domain expertise for this task.

**Feature extraction** is reducing the dimensionality of feature set from large set to smaller set. You will transform the feature set to less dimension feature set by  using algorithms like PCA - Principal component analysis etc.

Regarding your main query of generate values of features from data set is called **Feature engineering**. With the prominent growth of neural networks, you don't have to work on *Feature engineering / Feature extraction / Feature selection*. For a given set of data, the network learns the features by itself by observing the relation between data points.